# How to correctly resolve incompatible throw specifiers with implicit virtual destructors?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

This code does not compile:

```
#include <QString>

/* relevant part:
struct QString 
{
  ~QString() noexcept(false) {};
};
*/

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    QString string_;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
error: looser throw specifier for 'virtual Derived::~Derived()'
error:   overriding 'virtual Base::~Base() noexcept (true)'
```

I have no experience with using exceptions, but I think that the problem is that the `QString` destructor has no exception specifier and therefore the implicitly created `Derived::~Derived` has also no exception specifier. This is incompatible with the implicit `Base::~Base` which is `noexcept(true)`.

If I exclude the `QString` or replace it with a class with `noexcept(true)` (such as `std::string`), the code compiles.

At first I thought that I could solve this by declaring both destructors as `noexcept(false)`:

```
virtual ~Base() noexcept(false) = default;
virtual ~Derived() noexcept(false) = default;
```

But all I get is:

```
error: function 'virtual Base::~Base()' defaulted on its first declaration 
       with an exception-specification that differs from 
       the implicit declaration 'Base::~Base()'
error: looser throw specifier for 'virtual Derived::~Derived() noexcept (false)'
error: overriding 'virtual Base::~Base() noexcept (true)'
```

I do not use exceptions anywhere in my code, so the thing I am looking for is just a "fix".

Comment: Can't you just add `virtual ~Derived() = default;`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you, but I get the same error as in the first case.

Comment: What's the exception specification for `QString::~QString`?

Comment: inline ~QString(); that is no specification

Comment: Do you need a defaulted destructor, or would a user-provided destructor with no effect suffice? (`virtual ~Base() noexcept(false) { }`)

Comment: @hvd Thank you! It compiles, but I do not know how. I thought the two things are the same.

Comment: What's your compiler/

Comment: @MartinDrozdik They mean the same thing when the destructor is actually called, but they differ in compile-time detectable properties of the destructor.

Comment: They're not the same: yours is *not* a "user-provided" destructor, while hvd's version is. The difference is in the `is_trivially_destructible` property, and several other taxonomic details.

Comment: @KerrekSB Does it matter? This is correct behaviour according to C++11, is it not?

Comment: @hvd: I just can't reproduce this on my GCC 4.8.1...

Comment: @KerrekSB I am using GCC 4.7.3

Comment: @KerrekSB Interesting. Do you perhaps have a newer Qt that has a `nodefault` destructor for `QString`, or does it really depend on the compiler version?

Comment: @hvd: Have Qt4, not sure which exact version; but I also tried with my own test class with destructor `X::~X(){}` and it works fine.

Comment: @KerrekSB How about if you change that to `X::~X();`? There does seem to be a difference between GCC 4.7 and 4.8 though, so I'm now no longer sure what the correct behaviour is...

Comment: Then I have no explanation, and I don't have GCC 4.8 installed on this system to be able to test anything, unfortunately... I was convinced that the error message was correct, and if GCC 4.8 no longer shows that error message whereas GCC 4.7 does, that strongly suggests the error message was incorrect.

Comment: @hvd The example in 15.4/14 is very similar, and says that it would be ill-formed if a base class had virtual destructor.

Comment: Are you sure that `QString`'s destructor is declared with `noexcept(false)`? I can't see it in [Qt4.8 source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/tools/qstring.h), nor [Qt5](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/blobs/stable/src/corelib/tools/qstring.h). Is it the default behaviour in C++11 when nothing is specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem hosed by your QString, that specified itself throwing in dtor.

I see no easy ways out (beyond using a sensible string): you can bend in the wind specifying your base class dtor as noexcept(false) too, or make Derived dtor explicit and expressing noexcept(true).  (I'm not sure if anything good happens if ~QString actually thrown, but that leads toward the first escape route).

Comment: I believe that if a `nothrow(true)` dtor throws, `std::terminate` is called. Then again, I sincerely doubt the `QString` dtor actually throws - it just doesn't use an exception specification. And since it's been around much longer than C++11, it's hardly to blame (this time).