# exception specification for virtual function is incompatible with that of overridden function

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance, c++11, virtual

I get this error message with intel's `icpc` (version 14.0.1, using `-std=c++11`), while both clang (version 3.4) and gcc (version 4.8.1) are happy. A typical offending code is:

```
#include <vector>
namespace test {
  struct A
  {
    virtual bool foo(std::size_t) const = 0;
    virtual ~A() = default;
  };

  struct B
  : A
  {
    const std::vector<double> V;
    const double X;
    bool foo(std::size_t i) const { return V.at(i) > X; }
    virtual bool bar(std::size_t i) const { return V.at(i) < X; }
    B(double x, std::vector<double> const &v)
      : V(v), X(x) {}
    ~B() = default;
  };
}
```

Since `test::A` is abstract, is better has a virtual destructor. However,
icpc complains (compile error not a warning) about

> exception specification for virtual function "test::B::~B" is
>   incompatible with that of overridden function "test::A::~A"

I presume that all this is some bug of the intel compiler. Correct?

PS. I noticed a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295134/exception-specification-when-overriding-a-virtual-function), asked before C++11. I'm really concerned with C++11 when `throw` is deprecated (and replaced by `noexcept`).

Comment: Since B inherits from A, is there really any reason to declare its destructor?

Comment: I got this problem inheriting from std::exception

Comment: Is inheriting from a Standard library container a necessary part of the repro case?  You're not supposed to do that, anyway.

Comment: @BenVoigt No, it isn't. I just did that here for a SSCCE. I'll change.

Comment: SO related list found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273165/how-to-correctly-resolve-incompatible-throw-specifiers-with-implicit-virtual-des) worth looking at

Comment: @woolstar good point. In fact, avoiding to declare `B::~B()` avoids the error and does not generate the usual warning of a missing `virtual` destructor.

Answer (score 2):

This error message is suggesting that the destructor of your class has a different exception specification than the destructor of the base class. The compiler is implicitly declaring a destructor for your derived class, and there's an incompatibility.

To resolve this issue, explicitly define a destructor for your class with the appropriate exception specification to match that of the base class. Most likely, the base class destructor is declared `noexcept`.

```cpp
// ...

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    // Explicitly define a noexcept destructor
    virtual ~DerivedClass() noexcept = default;

    // ... (rest of your class definition)
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but 10 years later it is too late for me to validate your answer. So no tick.

Comment: Posting chatGPT responses as answers should be illegal on SO